# Get group member names from Get-Acl and Append to CSV

Tags: powershell, acl, active-directory-group

I need to extract all the members of a group and then format that into Names, so I only get the Full Names like "Don Joe" is member of my-domain\UNCShareDrive

I need that to appear in my CSV after I have exported the ACL lists.

***As an example:***

```
Path                                                                 FileSystemRights AccessControlType IdentityReference          
----                                                                 ---------------- ----------------- -----------------          
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\fileshare\management\DK           FullControl             Allow MY-DOMAIN\Drev Management
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\fileshare\management\           FullControl             Allow BUILTIN\Administratorer    
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\fileshare\management\     FullControl             Allow MY-DOMAIN\Drev Management
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\fileshare\management\     FullControl             Allow BUILTIN\Administratorer    




**These persons has access to the drive:**

**Finding group:  MY-DOMAIN\Administrators** 

Name                   SamAccountName Mail                     
----                   -------------- ----                     
Administrator          Administrator  Administrator@my-domain.dk
```

This is what I have so far done in Powershell:

```
$Searching = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=my-domain,DC=local"

$mypath = "U:\mytest.csv"

if((Test-Path -Path "U:\mytest.csv" -pathtype Container) -eq $True){
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "We found a file: $mypath --> REMOVING!`r`n"
  Remove-Item $mypath -Force
}

$ShareName = "\\\sharename\D$"

$shares = Get-Childitem -path $ShareName |
          Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
          Get-ACL |
          Select-Object Path -ExpandProperty Access |
          Select Path, FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IdentityReference |
          export-csv $mypath -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
$foldertotal = 0
Add-Content $mypath "" 
Add-Content $mypath "" 
Add-Content $mypath "Disse personer har adgang til share navnet"
Add-Content $mypath "" 
Add-Content $mypath ""

$myLoop = ''
foreach ($testLoop in $myLoop) {
  $Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=my-domain,DC=local" -Properties IdentityReference |
           Select-Object Name # Need only groups in $Shares - who are displayed
  $myLoop += Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Finding group: $($Group.name).....`n"
  $myLoop += ForEach ($Group in $share) {
               Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($Group.name) -recursive |
                 Get-ADUser -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Mail |
                 Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,Mail
             } 
  $testLoop | Out-File -filePath $mypath -append -encoding utf8
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "$($Group.name) is now exported to: $mypath`n"
```

I have also a hard time to filter out only the share path:

```
$shares.Replace('Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::', ' ') |
  Out-File -filePath $mypath -append -encoding utf8
```

---

How come that this thing Works when I use User Input and not just automatically loop through it without the console prompt:

```
$Searching = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "DC=MY-DOMAIN,DC=local"

$mypath = "U:\mytest.csv"
$networkPath = "\\ShareName\D$"
$acl = Get-acl -path $networkPath

if((Test-Path -Path "U:\mytest.csv" -pathtype Container) -eq $True){
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "We found a file: $mypath --> REMOVING!`r`n"
  Remove-Item $mypath -Force
}

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Eksempel på share: "`r`n\\ShareName\D$`r`n\\ShareTwo\\E$`r`n\\ShareName\management`r`n""
$ShareName = Read-host "Hvilket sharenavn vil du finde Access Control List fra?"
if($ShareName -eq "1"){
  $Sharename = "\\ShareName\D$"
}
if($ShareName -eq "2"){
  $Sharename = "\\ShareTwo\\E$"
}
if($ShareName -eq "3"){
  $Sharename = "\\ShareName\management"
}

Get-Childitem -path $ShareName |
  Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
  Get-ACL |
  Select-Object Path -ExpandProperty Access |
  Select Path, FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IdentityReference |
  FT -AutoSize |
  Out-File -Encoding utf8 $mypath
Add-Content $mypath "" 
Add-Content $mypath "" 
Add-Content $mypath "Disse personer har adgang til share navnet"
Add-Content $mypath "" 

$users = get-aduser -Filter {Name -Like "*"} -Searchbase "dc=MY-DOMAIN,dc=local" -Properties MemberOf |
         Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq 'True' }

Write-Host -ForegroundColor red "Example:  Drev Management`r`n"
$myGroups = Read-Host "Hvilken Gruppe vil du bruge?"
if($myGroups -eq "1"){
  $myGroups = " Drev Management"
}
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like $myGroups} | Select-Object Name 

Add-Content $mypath "Finding group: $($group.name)"
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Finding group: $($Group.name).....`n"
Add-Content -Path $mypath $result

ForEach ($Group in $Groups) {
  Get-ADGroupMember -identity $($Group.name) -recursive |
    Get-ADUser -Properties Name,SamAccountName,Mail |
    Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,Mail |
    FT -AutoSize |
    Out-File -Append -encoding utf8 $mypath
}
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "$($Group.name) is now exported to: $mypath`n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second code sample works, because it doesn't make the same mistakes as the first one.

```bsh
$myLoop = ''
foreach ($testLoop in $myLoop) {
  $Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter * ...
  $myLoop += Write-Host ...
  $myLoop += ForEach ($Group in $share) {
               Get-ADGroupMember ...
             } 
  $testLoop | Out-File -filePath $mypath -append -encoding utf8
}
```

- You make `$myLoop` an empty string, then iterate over each element of `$myLoop` (one empty string), so you get a single loop cycle, no matter what you append to `$myLoop` *inside* the loop.
- Instead of the group members you write the content of `$testLoop` (an empty string) to the output file.
- You read AD groups into the variable `$Group`, and then overwrite its content when you use `$Group` as the loop variable in `foreach ($Group in $share)`.
- `$share` is emtpy, because it's never initialized anywhere. Even `$shares` is empty, because when you write the ACL information to the CSV, no output is left that could be assigned to the variable.

And as a side-note: you can't append `Write-Host` output to anything, because the cmdlet writes to the host process (i.e. the console), not a stream that could be captured or redirected.

You need to capture the ACL information in `$shares` before writing it to a file:

```bsh
$shares = Get-Childitem -Path $ShareName |
          Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |
          Get-ACL |
          Select-Object Path -ExpandProperty Access |
          Select Path, FileSystemRights,AccessControlType,IdentityReference
$shares | Export-Csv $mypath -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Then you can determine the members of the groups having access to shares like this:

```bsh
$shares | Select-Object -Expand IdentityReference |
  Select-Object -Expand Value |
  ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_ -replace '^DOMAIN\\'  # <-- replace with actual domain name
    Get-ADObject -Filter { Name -eq $name }
  } |
  Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'group' } |
  Get-ADGroupMember |
  Get-ADUser -Properties * |
  Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Mail |
  Out-File $mypath -Append -Encoding UTF8
```

Note that this will not resolve nested groups, and also won't distinguish between shares.

If you want to store both the group name and its members you need to add a loop to the pipeline:

```bsh
$shares | Select-Object -Expand IdentityReference |
  Select-Object -Expand Value |
  ForEach-Object {
    $name = $_ -replace '^DOMAIN\\'  # <-- replace with actual domain name
    Get-ADObject -Filter { Name -eq $name }
  } |
  Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq 'group' } |
  ForEach-Object {
    $_
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ |
      Get-ADUser -Properties * |
      Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, Mail
  } |
  Out-File $mypath -Append -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: But How can I then add a loop that also print out each Group Name and then below that, the Groups members within this script, so it's more clear to visualize the data ? :). Thank you for giving the time to help me! - And sorry for the late comment, I have been overloaded with work.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you ! - This worked excatly how I wanted to! =)